# I want to be able to run iPython from any directory through Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, ipython

So I just switched over from the Enthought Canopy distribution to the Anaconda Distribution (had a lot of trouble installing modules in the Canopy version), and now I can't remember what, if anything I did to allow me to run iPython from any directory.

I can run both Python and iPython from the install directory, but this doesn't really help me as all my scripts are stored in various other directories.  I believe this is more of a Windows Command Line question, but I could be wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to add the Anaconda bin directory to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that from "System Properties"- "Advanced" tab. Client the "Environment Variables" on the bottom right. Then you can choose to edit the variable path. Append iphython directory into the path and press "OK". (Be careful only to append the directory into the "path" variable, do not delete old ones.)